# sql loader does not load empty lines inside char

Tags: sql-loader

I have a file `UNL_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE.dat` that contains the data below:

```
490319433|ProductAttribute||Electronic Instructions|CC - Emma Marshall - 4/2/13. Doc Id is 28248500
_____________________________________________________________________________
Peta Mayes 4/02/2013
DOC ID 08248500||||
490319515|ProductAttribute||Electronic Instructions|CC - Emma Marshall - 4/2/13. Doc Id is 28248500
_____________________________________________________________________________
Peta Mayes 4/02/2013
DOC ID 28248500||||
490319516|ProductAttribute||Electronic Instructions|CC - Emma Marshall - 4/2/13. Doc Id is 28248500
_____________________________________________________________________________
Peta Mayes
DOC ID 28248500||||
```

I am using a control file as below:

```
load data INFILE  'UNL_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE.dat' "STR '\N'"
append
into table UNL_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE
fields terminated by '|'  
(
PRODUCT_ID decimal external,
ATTRIBUTE_TYPE char(16),
ATTRIBUTE_GROUP decimal external,
ATTRIBUTE_NAME char(255),
ATTRIBUTE_VALUE  char(4000)  ,
CONTENT_ID char(4000),
CONTENT_VERSION char(4000),
CONTENT_TYPE char(4000))
```

My problem is that it is only loading the first entry, below.  All other entries are getting rejected. Please advise.

```
 490319433|ProductAttribute||Electronic Instructions|CC - Emma Marshall - 4/2/13. Doc Id is 28248500
_____________________________________________________________________________
Peta Mayes 4/02/2013
DOC ID 08248500||||
```

Please note that `|` is used as the delimiter here.

Answer (score 0):

If the multi-line field contains carriage returns that you want to preserve, the `INFILE` line should have `"str x'0D'"` at the end.
See this post for more information:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216660/2543416