# Line breaking issue to move csv file in Linux

Tags: regex, linux, perl, shell, sql-loader

[I have moved the csv file into Linux system with binary mode. File content of one field is spitted into multiple lines its comment sections,I need to remove the new line , keep the same format, Please help on shell command or perl command

here is the example for three records, Actual look like]
[Original content of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsd1Q.jpg)

[After moved into linux, comments field is splitted into 4 lines , i want to keep the comment field in the same format but dont want the new line characters

"First line

Second line

Third line
all lines format should not change"
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLOJ0.jpg)

Comment: What about the line  numbers? Also is there a blank line after each record
?

Comment: Do you want to remove *all* new lines in the the second column?

Comment: Hi sjsam,   actually line number is not required, keep the blank line as it is. going to load this field into oracle table using sql loader, consider two fields and three records is exist

Comment: I have used , as delimiter for csv

Comment: yes Ruslan, dont merge the lines , keep the blanklines as it is

Comment: I'm confused... Are the line numbers *in* the actual file? What change are you **actually** trying to make to the file here?

Comment: Hi Etan, I shown the line number for reference, I shown the diagram for long_text field , This is excel data while i moved into unix this field is splited and comes into many lines, i dont want to split it, want to keep the format same as input csv.

Comment: I'm afraid your specs are not clear and you included sql-loader as a tag but ask for a shell level solution.  Are you ultimately loading this data into an Oracle database and want to preserve the newlines in the comment field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment above, the specs are not clear but I suspect this is what you are trying to do.  Here's a way to load data into Oracle using `sqlldr` where a field is surrounded by double-quotes and contains linefeeds where the end of the record is a combination carriage return/linefeed. This can happen when the data comes from an Excel spreadsheet saved as a .csv for example, where the cell contains the linefeeds.

Here's the data file as exported by Excel as a .csv and viewed in gvim, with the option turned on to show control characters.  You can see the linefeeds as the `'$'` character and the carriage returns as the `'^M'` character:

```
100,test1,"1line1$
1line2$
1line3"^M$
200,test2,"2line1$
2line2$
2line3"^M$
```

Construct the control file like this using the `"str"` clause on the infile option line to set the end of record character.  It tells sqlldr that hex 0D (carriage return, or ^M) is the record separator (this way it will ignore the linefeeds inside the double-quotes):

```
LOAD DATA
infile "test.dat" "str x'0D'" 
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE test
replace
fields terminated by ","  
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
cola char,
colb char,
colc char
)
```

After loading, the data looks like this with linefeeds in the comment field (I called it colc) preserved:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from test;

COLA                 COLB                 COLC
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
100                  test1                1line1
                                          1line2
                                          1line3

200                  test2                2line1
                                          2line2
                                          2line3

SQL>
```

Comment: Hi Gary, Its working amazing, This is what i expected Thank you very much :)

Comment: Great, glad to hear it helped.