# check for newline character in a csv file

Tags: shell, awk, grep, gawk, sql-loader

currently in my code below line used to fix the newline break in a csv :

```
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' MY_FILE.csv > MY_FILE.csv.tmp
```

I want to do a pre check like if there is a new line break present in the file then only script will run the above command to fix that file, how do I add a pre check for this ?

my csv file looks as below and having 1 millions records in it :

```
20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","good data with.....some special character and space (new line)
space ..
....","M","072","00126"

20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","R","M","072","00126"
20160711,"M","N1","F","S","A","R","M","072","00126"
```

new line can appear anywhere in the file .

Comment: Please describe in more detail the file you are loading.  Is the newline embedded in a field like a comment field?  Would you want to preserve that newline in a comment field if you could?  Does the newline occur on every line?  etc.  Show a before and after example of actual data. I suspect the issue you are trying to solve can be handled in the control file but it is not quite clear.

Comment: @Gary_W I have updated my question , please have a look . its a csv file which I am trying to fix prior to loading using sql loader

Comment: Where's the "good data with.." in the after example (see "R" that is not in the original data)?  Are you sure you don't want to preserve the carriage returns in that field (otherwise you are altering input data and will not be able to reproduce exactly what was entered)? I suspect they came from a free-form multi-line text field where the users were allowed to enter a carriage return.

Comment: Do your lines end with `\r\n` or just `\n`? Is the newline inside the field `\n` or `\r\n`? Can you have escaped quotes within your quoted fields, e.g. `"you're \"cool\", huh?"`?

Answer (score 1):

@sabya Perhaps count the double quotes on a line?  If odd, then there is a return somewhere:

```
gawk '{if (and(1,gsub(/"/, "\"")) HasReturn = 1; exit} END {exit HasReturn}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would respectfully suggest you load the data as given and not alter it in order to maintain data integrity by constructing the control file to preserve the newline between the double-quotes.

Construct the control file like this using the "str" clause on the infile option line to set the end of record character. It tells sqlldr that hex 0D (carriage return, or ^M) is the record separator (this way it will ignore the linefeeds inside the double-quotes):

```
LOAD DATA
infile "test.dat" "str x'0D'" 
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE test
replace
fields terminated by ","  
optionally enclosed by '"'
(
cola char,
colb char,
colc char
)
```

More info in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216660/2543416