# str in control file is not working to load csv data having carriage return and line feed

Tags: java, linux, oracle, csv, sql-loader

I am trying to load (using sqlldr) a csv file from linux system to oracle database where a column is having data which has carriage return and line feed.

Control File looks as below:

```
OPTIONS (DIRECT = TRUE, SKIP = 1, ERRORS=0)
unrecoverable load data
CHARACTERSET UTF8
infile 'abc.csv'  "str '\r\n'" 
into table USER1."ABC"
Append
fields terminated by "," optionally enclosed by '"'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
("COLUMN1" CONSTANT 100,
"COLUMN2",
"COLUMN3" CONSTANT  'XYZ',
"COLUMN4")
```

CSV File looks as below:

```
COLUMN2, COLUMN4
"abc1","abc2
welcome"
"ok","abc4"
```

I have tried following things in control file but load was successful with zero row insertion to the table:

```
 1. "str '\r\n'"
 2. "str '#EOR#'"
 3. "str x'0D'"
 4. "str '\n'"
```

"str '\n'":This generates .bad file. Content of .bad file is as below:

```
"abc1","abc2
```

Is there anything that is being missed? Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like your input data is 'corrupted'.  "abc2 welcome" seems to have an embedded record terminator between the field delimiters (double-quote).

Comment: @EdStevens, there is record terminator (carriage return and line feed between "abc2" and "welcome"). It's the requirement to load such data. So, it's possible to load the data if record terminator is present in the data?

Comment: For more information, please see this post where I offered a solution to this very problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37216660/2543416

Answer (score 1):

**Have The Data Adhere to the Stream Record Format You Have Identified**

You are using the [Stream Record Format](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-concepts.html#GUID-C6D10BF6-F6C0-476C-B924-7A081C70DBC2) and you are indicating each record ends with `\r\n`.

Based on the *.bad file, your data file records end with `\n` and not `\r\n` (standard Unix line ending behavior).

Can you change your stream record format's end of record to, `|\n`, and add a `|` at the end of every record in your data?

You would change this line:

```
infile 'abc.csv'  "str '\r\n'
```

to

```
infile 'abc.csv'  "str '|\n'
```

The data would change to this:

```
"abc1","abc2
welcome"|
"ok","abc4"|
```